# Restriction Forces in Lagrangian Mechanics

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

I was recently preparing for a test on Classical Mechanics and a friend of mine started wondering if there was any method through which we could obtain the restriction forces acting on a certain particle *without* using the Lagrange Multipliers method. At first glance my feeling would be that since Lagrangian Mechanics deals primarily with action and energies and not with forces, the answer would be no. But I'm really curious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, if the constraints are [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) one doesn't need Lagrange multipliers to solve the Lagrange equations.

Comment: I see. Can restriction forces be calculated without issue in that case? I'm not trying to obtain equations of motion or conserved quantities. How would one go about obtaining the RF's in the case of holonomic restraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the constraints are [holonomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) one doesn't need Lagrange multipliers to solve Lagrange equations $$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^j}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^j}~=~Q^a_j,\qquad j~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\},\tag{1}$$
   where $$Q^a_j~=~\sum_{i=1}^N {\bf F}^a_i\cdot \frac{\partial {\bf r}_i}{\partial q^j},\qquad j~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\},\tag{2}$$ is the $j$'th applied [generalized force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_forces).
2. The constraint force ${\bf F}^c_{i}$ on the $i$'th point particle with position $${\bf r}_i(q^1, \ldots, q^n,t),\qquad i~\in~\{1,\ldots, N\},\tag{3}$$ 
   can then in principle be reconstructed via Newton's 2nd law 
   $${\bf F}^c_{i}~=~\dot{\bf p}_i-{\bf F}^a_i,\tag{4}$$ 
   where ${\bf F}_i^a$ is the applied force from eq. (2).
3. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290879/2451) related Phys.SE post.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chapters 1 & 2.